# Parent case field to be auto filled when child case is closed

Tags: trigger, workflow

I have a scenario when any child case is closed,  two fields in the parent case needs to be updated.
If there is more than one child, the parent will be updated with the most recent child case that was closed.
One field is a Date/time field, the other one is a check box.  Both are read only fields.

Do you all think is this achievable by workflow rules or should i write a trigger for this

Comment: the first question you should be able to research yourself - Can a field update on a child Case update a field in the parent Case?  Experiment with workflows to see if doable.